# I am trying to parse two JSON objects retrieved from text fields in my HTML to retrieve values from the JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, forms

Like the title says, a user inputs into two fields on my HTML file. I am trying to take these two fields, assign them a variable in JS and depending on what they type in, a result is given from a JSON file. Am I missing something? I can get it to work if I am just using one user-inputted value, but I cannot seem to make two values work properly. Here is the link to the JSON file:[JSON File](https://facweb.cdm.depaul.edu/sjost/cities.js)

```
function listCities() {
    var c = document.getElementById("country");
    var s = document.getElementById("subcountry");
    var answer = document.getElementById("textarea1");
    var citiesArray = JSON.parse(data);
    var output = ""
    for(obj of citiesArray) {
        if(obj.country == c.value && obj.subcounty == s.value) {
            output += `${obj.name}\n`;
        }
    }
    answer.value = output;
}
```

Comment: please include `data` in your question

Comment: `obj.subcountry`.. not `obj.subcounty`. Anyway I would really like to suggest people to spend one minute to better read their text before taking the effort to ask a question here.

Comment: https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/49679035/one-typo-in-code-day-spent-analyzing-data-wasted-.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I just created a working demo and it is working fine. Please have a look and let me know if any further changes required as part of the requirement.

```js
function listCities() {
    var c = document.getElementById("country");
    var s = document.getElementById("subcountry");
    var answer = document.getElementById("textarea1");
    var citiesArray = [{
        country: 'country1',
      subcountry: 'subcountry1',
      name: 'name1'
    }, {
      country: 'country1',
      subcountry: 'subcountry1',
      name: 'name2'
    }, {
      country: 'country1',
      subcountry: 'subcountry1',
      name: 'name3'
    }];
    var output = ""
    for(obj of citiesArray) {
        if(obj.country == c.value && obj.subcountry == s.value) {
            output += `${obj.name}\n`;
        }
    }
    answer.value = output;
}
```

```html
Country : <input type="text" id="country" name="country"/>
Sub Country : <input type="text" id="subcountry" name="subcountry"/>
<input type="button" value="List Cities" onclick="listCities()"/>
<br><br>
<textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! I see what changes you made and they all make sense, however when I run your code on both my end and also in stack overflow, It still does not work.

Comment: When I input `country1` in country box and `subcountry1` in Sub Country box and press `List Cities` button. It is populating all the names in the textarea related to the search.

Answer (score -1):

The `JSON.parse()` function returns with an object, not an array. Perhaps that makes error.
You have wrong typing: `obj.subcounty`.

Comment: That's not true. [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) can return `null`, a boolean, a string, a number, an object or an array. Please don't answer a question that only contains a typo.